# Ruby on Rails - Drop down list triggers another one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project model, and related to this model I have course and course unit models.

When I created a project I wanted to choose a course and depending on the course I chose, I wanted to choose a course unit from the drop down list.

I have this 3 models

```
class CourseUnit < ApplicationRecord                                      
    belongs_to :course
    has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :course_units, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :course_units
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord   
    belongs_to :course_unit
end
```

Anyone have any idea how I can do it?

This is my Project table:

```
 create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.text     "resume"
    t.text     "github"
    t.text     "grade"
    t.text     "project_url"
    t.date     "date"
    t.boolean  "finished"
    t.boolean  "featured"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "course_unit_id"
    t.index ["course_unit_id"], name: "index_projects_on_course_unit_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_on_user_id"
  end
```

I just have the atribute course_unit_id.

The course is related with project `through: :course_units`

How can i have a list of courses in the `_form.html.erb`?

Comment: Basically, with javascript.  There is an excellent Railscast on this... http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus?autoplay=true

Comment: If not with JavaScript, you can submit the form `onChange` event, and make the selections in ERB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Heres a good example in rails 5:

https://rubyplus.com/articles/3691-Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-5

Comment: please summarize the sample here